# catch exception getting ReferenceError in node js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

i'm new to node js. I need to add language details into my couchbase database. i could not able to create records into database.

```
      exports.createlanguage = function(req, res){
            var common = new Common(req.body);
            common.create().then(result =>{
                res.status(200).send({ status: 'success', resCode: 200,msg:"Language Added Successfully", data: result });
            }).catch(function (error){
                res.status(403).send({ status: 'error', resCode: 403, msg: 'Internal Server Error...!', data: error });
            }); 
}
```

This is my common module

```
var ottoman = require('ottoman');
var langMdl = ottoman.model('languages',{
    langId: {type:'string', auto:'uuid', readonly:true},
    languageName:'string', 
    creadtedDate:{type: 'Date', default:function(){return new Date()}},
})
module.exports = langMdl;
```

**ReferenceError: Common is not defined** this is the error getting whenever  run my request in postman. Kindly help anyone

Comment: Did u forget to import `Common` module of your project?

Comment: **var common=require('../../model/common/common.model');** this is my common module @SureshPrajapati

Answer (score 1):

`common` and `Common` will be two different variables. Also, it is confusing with the local `common` variable inside the handler.

Modified your code a little:

```
var commonModule = require('../../model/common/common.model');

exports.createlanguage = function(req, res){
    var common = new commonModule();
    common.create(req.body).then(result =>{
        res.status(200).send({ status: 'success', resCode: 200,msg:"Language Added Successfully", data: result });
    }).catch(function (error){
        res.status(403).send({ status: 'error', resCode: 403, msg: 'Internal Server Error...!', data: error });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: i have changed my code but i'm getting new error like **TypeError: common.create is not a function** @SureshPrajapati

Comment: are you using es6?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Can you add code inside common.module to check if export/import is correct.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati i have added my common.module codes

Comment: @NaveenKumar I found no reference for `create` function here https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman Did u mean `save`?